# flex auto update script showing error

Tags: apache-flex, air

I want to enable auto update script in flex3. i am using below code to do this but flex editor showing red mark on line 39 and editor show error when i hover my mouse on red mark is:

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: UpdateEvent.

how can i remove this error. please guide me.

```
    // Instantiate the updater
    private var appUpdater:ApplicationUpdaterUI = new ApplicationUpdaterUI();

    private function checkForUpdate():void {
        // The code below is a hack to work around a bug in the framework so that CMD-Q still works on MacOS
        // This is a temporary fix until the framework is updated
        // See http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/webforums/forum/messageview.cfm?forumid=72&catid=670&threadid=1373568
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener( Event.EXITING, 
            function(e:Event):void {
                var opened:Array = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows;
                for (var i:int = 0; i < opened.length; i ++) {
                    opened[i].close();
                }
        });    

        setApplicationVersion(); // Find the current version so we can show it below

        // Configuration stuff - see update framework docs for more details
        appUpdater.updateURL = "http://www.mytoplinks.net/flex/update.xml"; // Server-side XML file describing update
        appUpdater.isCheckForUpdateVisible = false; // We won't ask permission to check for an update
        appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED, onUpdate); // Once initialized, run onUpdate
        appUpdater.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError); // If something goes wrong, run onError
        appUpdater.initialize(); // Initialize the update framework
    }

    private function onError(event:ErrorEvent):void {
        Alert.show(event.toString());
    }

    private function onUpdate(event:UpdateEvent):void {
        appUpdater.checkNow(); //Go check for an update now
    }

    // Find the current version for our Label below
    private function setApplicationVersion():void {
        var appXML:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
        var ns:Namespace = appXML.namespace();
        ver.text = "Current version is " + appXML.ns::version;
    }
]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox backgroundColor="blue" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:Label color="white" id="ver" />
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an import to UpdateEvent to the top of the script section

```
import air.update.events.UpdateEvent;
```

hth

Koen